# Rewrite MutationObserver() with async/await

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, mutation-observers, mutation

How can I write this mutation observer code, using **async/await**?

I want to `return true` after `console.log("Button is appearing...");`.  Could someone show me the best way to write this code?

I also need to clarify, this code is watching for a button, which appears and then disappears.  And the reappears again, multiple times.

So the `mutationObserver`, is watching for the button to appear multiple times. Not just once.

```
var target = document.querySelector('[search-model="SearchPodModel"]')
var observer = new MutationObserver(mutate);

function mutate(mutations) {
    for (let i = 0; i < mutations.length; i++) {
        if (mutations[i].oldValue === "ej-button rounded-corners arrow-button search-submit holiday-search ng-hide") {
            console.log("Button is appearing...");
            return true;
        };
    };
};

var config = { childList: true, attributes: true, characterData: true, subtree: true, attributeOldValue: true };
observer.observe(target, config);
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you want this as a one-time thing? Unsubscribing the observer once you've settled the promise? Not as a series of notifications? (Since promises are a one-off thing.)

Comment: Thats right, @T.J.Crowder- I would actually need this to fire multiple times, as the button appears/disappears multiple times.  I'm kinda struggling with this, as all the solutions I run into is promises/async await, but they all only resolve once?  Also tried passing in another callback, but thats where my coding expertise goes grey. Keen to learn, but don't know how to get about this one...

Comment: Then promises (and thus `async`/`await`, which is syntax for using promises) isn't the right model for what you're doing. You want something that's often called an "observable" that provides a stream of events, not just one fulfillment/rejection.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder - can you recommend where to ready more about "observable?"

Comment: It's not an area I've really gotten into, but I've heard of [Rx.js](https://rxjs.dev/) often...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preface: I would strongly recommend **not** relying on a mutation observer to watch for a button's class attribute to change. It's very much a last resort thing to do. Look for anything else you can hook into that happens which is what makes the button appear/disappear and hook into that instead.

But getting to your question:

Since you want repeated notifications, promises (and thus `async`/`await`) is not the right model for this. A promise is only settled once.

There's no JavaScript built-in for it, but what you want is often called an *observable* and it has (typically) `subscribe` and `unsubscribe` methods. Here's a *really* basic, naive implementation of an observable (using modern JavaScript; run it through Babel or similar if you need to support older environments), but you may want to go looking for a library (such as [Rx.js](https://rxjs.dev/) — not an endorsement, I haven't used it, just an example I happen to know about) with something more feature-rich and, you know, tested:

```
class Observable {
    // Constructs the observable
    constructor(setup) {
        // Call the observable executor function, give it the function to call with
        // notifications.
        setup((spent, value) => {
            // Do the notifications
            this.#notifyObservers(spent, value);
            if (spent) {
                // Got a notification that the observable thing is completely done and
                // won't be providing any more updates. Release the observers.
                this.#observers = null;
            }
        });
    }

    // The observers
    #observers = new Set();

    // Notify observers
    #notifyObservers(spent, value) {
        // Grab the current list to notify
        const observers = new Set(this.#observers);
        for (const observer of observers) {
            try { observer(spent, value); } catch { }
        }
    }

    // Add an observer. Returns a true if the subscription was successful, false otherwise.
    // You can't subscribe to a spent observable, and you can't subscribe twice.
    subscribe(observer) {
        if (typeof observer !== "function") {
            throw new Error("The observer must be a function");
        }
        if (this.#observers.has(observer) || !this.#observers) {
            return false;
        }
        this.#observers.add(observer);
        return true;
    }

    // Remove an observer. Returns true if the unsubscription was successful, false otherwise.
    unsubscribe(observer) {
        return this.#observers ? this.#observers.delete(observer) : false;
    }
}
```

Then you might create an observable for this mutation:

```
// Create an observable for the button
const buttonAppearedObservable = new Observable(notify => {
    const target = document.querySelector('[search-model="SearchPodModel"]');
    const observer = new MutationObserver(mutate);

    function mutate(mutations) {
        for (const mutation of mutations) {
            if (mutation.oldValue === "ej-button rounded-corners arrow-button search-submit holiday-search ng-hide") {
                // Notify observers. The first argument is `false` because this observable isn't "spent" (it may still
                // send more notifications). If you wanted to pass a value, you'd pass a second argument.
                notify(
                    false,          // This observable isn't "spent"
                    mutation.target // Pass along the mutation target element (presumably the button?)
                );
            };
        };
    };

    // Set up the observer
    const config = { childList: true, attributes: true, characterData: true, subtree: true, attributeOldValue: true };
    observer.observe(target, config);
});
```

Once you'd set that observable up, you could subscribe to it:

```
buttonAppearedObservable.subscribe((spent, button) => {
    if (spent) {
        // This is a notification that the button appeared event will never happen again
    }
    if (button) {
        // The button appeared!
        console.log(`Button "${button.value}" appeared!`);
    }
});
```

Live Exmaple:

```js
class Observable {
    // Constructs the observable
    constructor(setup) {
        // Call the observable executor function, give it the function to call with
        // notifications.
        setup((spent, value) => {
            // Do the notifications
            this.#notifyObservers(spent, value);
            if (spent) {
                // Got a notification that the observable thing is completely done and
                // won't be providing any more updates. Release the observers.
                this.#observers = null;
            }
        });
    }

    // The observers
    #observers = new Set();

    // Notify observers
    #notifyObservers(spent, value) {
        // Grab the current list to notify
        const observers = new Set(this.#observers);
        for (const observer of observers) {
            try { observer(spent, value); } catch { }
        }
    }

    // Add an observer. Returns a true if the subscription was successful, false otherwise.
    // You can't subscribe to a spent observable, and you can't subscribe twice.
    subscribe(observer) {
        if (typeof observer !== "function") {
            throw new Error("The observer must be a function");
        }
        if (this.#observers.has(observer) || !this.#observers) {
            return false;
        }
        this.#observers.add(observer);
        return true;
    }

    // Remove an observer. Returns true if the unsubscription was successful, false otherwise.
    unsubscribe(observer) {
        return this.#observers ? this.#observers.delete(observer) : false;
    }
}

// Create an observable for the button
const buttonAppearedObservable = new Observable(notify => {
    const target = document.querySelector('[search-model="SearchPodModel"]');
    const observer = new MutationObserver(mutate);

    function mutate(mutations) {
        for (const mutation of mutations) {
            if (mutation.oldValue === "ej-button rounded-corners arrow-button search-submit holiday-search ng-hide") {
                // Notify observers. The first argument is `false` because this observable isn't "spent" (it may still
                // send more notifications). If you wanted to pass a value, you'd pass a second argument.
                notify(
                    false,          // This observable isn't "spent"
                    mutation.target // Pass along the mutation target element (presumably the button?)
                );
            };
        };
    };

    // Set up the observer
    const config = { childList: true, attributes: true, characterData: true, subtree: true, attributeOldValue: true };
    observer.observe(target, config);
});

buttonAppearedObservable.subscribe((spent, button) => {
    if (spent) {
        // This is a notification that the button appeared event will never happen again
    }
    if (button) {
        // The button appeared!
        console.log(`Button "${button.value}" appeared!`);
    }
});

// Stand-in code to make a button appear/disappear every second
let counter = 0;
let button = document.querySelector(`[search-model="SearchPodModel"] input[type=button]`);
let timer = setInterval(() => {
    if (button.classList.contains("ng-hide")) {
        ++counter;
    } else if (counter >= 10) {
        console.log("Stopping the timer");
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = 0;
        return;
    }
    button.value = `Button ${counter}`;
    button.classList.toggle("ng-hide");
}, 500);
```

```css
.ng-hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- NOTE: `search-model` isnt' a valid attribute for any DOM element. Use the data-* prefix for custom attributes -->
<div search-model="SearchPodModel">
    <input type="button" class="ej-button rounded-corners arrow-button search-submit holiday-search ng-hide" value="The Button">
</div>
```

All of that is **very** off-the-cuff. Again, you might look for robust libraries, etc.

Comment: This is amazing, thank you so much @T.J. Crowder!  I have to be honest, I've not had to work too much with classes whilst working as. Front-End dev, but this is a great example for me to try and get my head around this and practice.  Really appreciate the explanation on this and also the reference to Rx.js.  Thank you so much for this!  I'm going to spend some time now to recreate this and get this work.

Comment: Honestly, I've been bashing my head on this one for the last 2 days and your explanation and solution, is the only one that has really helped and explained why none of the other solutions were an option. Thank you so much again for your time and effort @T.J Crowder :)

Comment: @ReenaVerma - :-) I'm really glad that helped!!